# Whats a cleaner way to write this javascript if statement?

Tags: javascript

I've tried the format like

```
['mobile-number', 'name', 'about'].includes(stages)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

```
if (stages.includes('mobile-number') || stages.includes('name') || stages.includes('about')) {
    array.push('about-you')
}
```

Comment: Use [`every`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) or [`some`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)?

Comment: what is the type of `stages` ? is it another array? or a normal string?

Answer (score 3):

Your looking for `Array.prototype.some`

```
stages.some(s => ['mobile-number', 'name', 'about'].includes(s))
```

This is the exact alternative of `stages.includes('mobile-number') || stages.includes('name') || stages.includes('about')`

Comment: The caveat is stages type is unknown as OP missed it, hope its string, else you need to update the answer with the assumption that its a string type

Comment: Though, we can guess that. Because if it's String, there is NO complexity , and it must be `[...].includes(stages)`.. however, the semantic of question should mean a relationship between 2 arrays, not array+string

Comment: yeah unknowns and assumptions are the greatest enemies, totally agree what you said, but the facts are still unknown